# uso de loc en pandas

Tags: pandas

estoy tratando de cambiar los valores vacios en un data frame por una frase como "no registrado".Apliqué el método loc de la siguiente manera:

```py
ff_df = final_df.loc[final_df[' Computer_OS'] == ' ', ' Computer_OS'] = 'no registrado'
```

pero me sale el siguiente error, qué estaré haciendo mal?

```
 A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  isetter(loc, value)
no registrado
```

Comment: Hee... cual es el error??

Comment: también puedes usar `df["Computer_OS"].replace("", "no registrado")`

Comment: pero con esa instrucción que mencionas no lo escribe sobre el data frame original, de hecho sí lo escribo así como dices: 

final_df[' Computer_OS'] =final_df[" Computer_OS"].replace("", "no registrado")
me sale lo siguiente:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:19: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Lo mejor es que coloques una parte de tu DataFrame (como texto) para así poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: Mi dataframe es así:

 Employee_ID Age Education_Level Computer_OS Computer_tickets Mobile_OS
0 EID_22713 32.0 5 MacOS 0 iOS
1 EID_9658 65.0 2 Windows 9 Android
2 EID_22203 52.0 3 Windows 0 Android
3 EID_7652 50.0 5 Windows 0 iOS
4 EID_6516 44.0 3 Windows 5 Android

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/486772/edit) tu pregunta para agregarlo ahí

Comment: Prueba sin la asignación, o sea: `final_df.loc[final_df[' Computer_OS'] == ' ', ' Computer_OS'] = 'no registrado'`

Answer (score 0):

No es un error. Es un warning.

Probablemente el `DataFrame` que has generado `final_df` lo has hecho a partir de otro que está apuntando en la misma localización de la memoria.

Para solucionar el warning, deberías haber usado en la definición de la variable `final_df` la función `.copy()`:

```py
final_df = df[...].copy()
```